# I am trying to create a SQL statement that will result in - column 1: column header, column 2: (whether the column is populated by data or not)

Tags: sql, loops, exists, information-schema, case-statement

```
Select 
    column_name,
    Case 
       When Exist (Select * from information schema.columns
                   Where table_name = 'table 1'
                     And column_name in (Select column_name 
                                         from information_schema.columns 
                                         Where table_name = 'table 1'))
          Then 'populated'
          Else 'not populated'
```

End as Results

```
From 
    information_schema.columns
Where 
    table_name = ‘table 1'
```

—- case statement not looping for every individual column name on left

Comment: The sql is working but the looping on checking each individual columns seems to not work.

Comment: This SQL **cannot** be working since you've missed the `End` for the `Case` expression .....

Comment: Oh right, apologies. I left it out. I had a'end as results' when i ran it but the second column seems to be just filled with ‘populated’. It seems that my query did not look into individual columns to return a result on whether it is populated or not, rather it just looked into all columns and just return a fixed result throughout all rows